# I'm coding a discord bot using discord.js in VSC and all commands are responding except one, which is a ticket command I'm trying to create

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm currently working on coding a full AIO Discord Bot, such as ones you see like "Dyno Bot" or "Carl Bot" and I've completed making basic commands such as `ping`, `avatar`, etc.

I'm moving on to a more complex command such as a ticket system command. I've completed the entire code and the terminal logs into the bot just fine but for some reason, the command isn't responding. I checked the other commands just to make sure and it's only this specific command. I'm sure the solution is probably a dumb one, but any help is appreciated.

`index.js`:

```js
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const fs = require('fs');
const { Client, Collection, Intents, DiscordAPIError } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');
const prefex = '/';

const memberCounter = require('./counters/member-counter');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
  ],
});

client.commands = new Collection();
client.events = new Collection();
const commandFiles = fs
  .readdirSync('./commands')
  .filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log("You are now connected to Boombap's Cookout!");
  memberCounter(client);
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
  if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

  const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

  if (!command) return;

  try {
    await command.execute(interaction);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return interaction.reply({
      content: 'There was an error while executing this command!',
      ephemeral: true,
    });
  }
});

// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
```

`ticket.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'ticket',
  aliases: [],
  permissions: [],
  description: 'open a ticket!',
  async execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord) {
    const channel = await message.guild.channels.create(
      `ticket: ${message.author.tag}`,
    );

    channel.setParent('932184344011898890');

    channel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.id, {
      SEND_MESSAGE: false,
      VIEW_CHANNEL: false,
    });
    channel.updateOverwrite(message.author, {
      SEND_MESSAGE: true,
      VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
    });

    const reactionMessage = await channel.send(
      'Thank you for contacting support!',
    );

    try {
      await reactionMessage.react('');
      await reactionMessage.react('⛔');
    } catch (err) {
      channel.send('Error sending emojis!');
      throw err;
    }

    const collector = reactionMessage.createReactionCollector(
      (reaction, user) =>
        message.guild.members.cache
          .find((member) => member.id === user.id)
          .hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR'),
      { dispose: true },
    );

    collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
      switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
        case '':
          channel.updateOverwrite(message.author, { SEND_MESSAGES: false });
          break;
        case '⛔':
          channel.send('Deleting this channel in 5 seconds!');
          setTimeout(() => channel.delete(), 5000);
          break;
      }
    });

    message.channel
      .send(`We will be right with you! ${channel}`)
      .then((msg) => {
        setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 7000);
        setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 3000);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        throw err;
      });
  },
};
```

Comment: Does the bot create the channel, assign category, and set permissions? Does your bot have necessary permissions?

Comment: yes my bot has the necessary permissions and yes it also creates the channel but I assigned the category myself in the channel.setParent('');

Comment: wdym? like as in what happens after?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're using v13 of discord.js and still having some v12 syntax.

First, `channel.updateOverwrite()` is [`channel.permissionOverwrites.edit()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/PermissionOverwriteManager?scrollTo=edit) now. Second, `member.hasPermission()` became [`member.permissions.has()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=has) with the latest major update. You can read more about these changes on [discordjs.guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html).

Another error is that you're using the `SEND_MESSAGE` flag, but it's `SEND_MESSAGES`. An there is one more, you're using the `filter` for [`createReactionCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector) incorrectly.

Check out the code below, it works fine for me:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'ticket',
  aliases: [],
  permissions: [],
  description: 'open a ticket!',
  async execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord) {
    const channel = await message.guild.channels.create(
      `ticket: ${message.author.tag}`,
    );

    channel.setParent('932184344011898890');

    channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(message.guild.id, {
      SEND_MESSAGES: false,
      VIEW_CHANNEL: false,
    });
    channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(message.author, {
      SEND_MESSAGES: true,
      VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
    });

    const reactionMessage = await channel.send(
      'Thank you for contacting support!',
    );

    try {
      await reactionMessage.react('');
      await reactionMessage.react('⛔');
    } catch (err) {
      channel.send('Error sending emojis!');
      throw err;
    }

    const filter = (reaction, user) =>
      message.guild.members.cache
        .find((member) => member.id === user.id)
        .permissions.has('ADMINISTRATOR');

    const collector = reactionMessage.createReactionCollector({
      dispose: true,
      filter,
    });

    collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
      switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
        case '':
          channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(message.author, { SEND_MESSAGES: false });
          break;
        case '⛔':
          channel.send('Deleting this channel in 5 seconds!');
          setTimeout(() => channel.delete(), 5000);
          break;
      }
    });

    message.channel
      .send(`We will be right with you! ${channel}`)
      .then((msg) => {
        setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 7000);
        setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 3000);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        throw err;
      });
  },
};
```

After cleaning up your original code, I noticed that you're using slash commands. It means you have to make lots of small changes. And your original `execute()` method that receives several parameters (`async execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord)`) only receive a single one; `intereaction`.

Here is the code that works as a slash command, I've added some comments to explain the changes:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'ticket',
  aliases: [],
  permissions: [],
  description: 'open a ticket!',
  async execute(interaction) {
    // message.guild is now interaction.guild
    const channel = await interaction.guild.channels.create(
      // message.author.tag is now interaction.user.tag
      `ticket: ${interaction.user.tag}`,
    );

    channel.setParent('932184344011898890');

    // message.guild is now interaction.guild
    channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(interaction.guild.id, {
      SEND_MESSAGES: false,
      VIEW_CHANNEL: false,
    });

    // message.author is now interaction.member
    channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(interaction.member, {
      SEND_MESSAGES: true,
      VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
    });

    // we're sending a reply with interaction.reply
    // and use fetchReply so we can delete it after 7 seconds
    const reply = await interaction.reply({
      content: `We will be right with you! ${channel}`,
      fetchReply: true,
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      reply.delete();
    }, 7000);

    const reactionMessage = await channel.send(
      'Thank you for contacting support!',
    );

    try {
      await reactionMessage.react('');
      await reactionMessage.react('⛔');
    } catch (err) {
      channel.send('Error sending emojis!');
      throw err;
    }
    // you should also check if the user reacted is a bot
    const filter = (reaction, user) =>
      !user.bot &&
      interaction.guild.members.cache
        .get(user.id)
        .permissions.has('ADMINISTRATOR');

    const collector = reactionMessage.createReactionCollector({
      dispose: true,
      filter,
    });

    collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
      switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
        case '':
          channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(interaction.member, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
          });
          break;
        case '⛔':
          channel.send('Deleting this channel in 5 seconds!');
          setTimeout(() => channel.delete(), 5000);
          break;
      }
    });
  },
};
```

Comment: I'm sadly still getting an error, is it possible it has something to do with my index. js?

Comment: it's not an error but more of the command still not executing or responding

Comment: Oh, found another error, that's the filter not being set up correctly. Let me update the code above.

Comment: so its looking like it's still not executing, but no errors in the terminal itself im going to comment my index.js and maybe you can spot an error within it

Comment: ```const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');
const prefix = '!';

const memberCounter = require('./counters/member-counter');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS] });

client.commands = new Collection();


const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));```

Comment: ```for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}```

Comment: Oh, wait. Are you using slash commands? It's a lot more work to update everything then...

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vVi2Bl7oqG2grXbJS0y3VnVO9_83Vg6W/view?usp=sharing this is my index.js in .txt format so you can review it, I didn't know how else to share it so I uploaded it to google drive

Comment: after reviewing the edited code, will i have to change anything within my index.js? or my deploy-commands.js?

Comment: Your [original `index.js`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70728468/6126373) looks good to me. I'm not sure if you've already added the ticket command in your `deploy-commands.js` file though...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241099/discussion-between-senpai-and-zsolt-meszaros).

Comment: I have message you through chat! whenever you get a chance please message me there as Stackoverflow has asked me to bring the conversation over there