# Allow users to send suggestion for the bot to create and send an embed with two emojis to vote

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a discord bot that will where someone can enter the slash command `/suggestion` and the bot will take that suggestion and turn it into an embed and send it into a specific suggestions channel with two emojis, an X and Checkmark.

After getting it all written and doing `node deploy-commands.js` and getting no errors, I inputted `node .` with also no errors in the terminal.

But when I went into the discord and enter the `/suggestions` command, I get an error in the terminal which is:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'join')

and I have no idea how to follow the error to see where it's originating from.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

I'll leave my index.js, suggestions.js, and deploy-commands.js below.

index.js

```
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const fs = require('fs');
const { Client, Collection, Intents, } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
    ],
});

client.commands = new Collection();
client.events = new Collection();
const commandFiles = fs
    .readdirSync('./commands')
    .filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log("You are now connected to Boombap Suggestions!");
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return interaction.reply({
            content: 'There was an error while executing this command!',
            ephemeral: true,
        });
    }
});

// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
```

suggestions.js

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'suggestions',
    aliases: ['suggest', 'suggestion'],
    permissions: [],
    description: 'creates a suggestion!',
    execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord) {
        const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === 'suggestions');
        if (!channel) return message.channel.send('suggestions channel does not exist!');

        let messageArgs = args.join(' ');
        const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('5104DB')
            .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
            .setDescription(messageArgs);

        channel.send(embed).then((msg) => {
            msg.react('❌');
            msg.react('✅');
            message.delete();
        }).catch((err) => {
            throw err;
        });
    }
}
```

deploy-commands.js

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');

const commands = [
    new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('suggestions').setDescription('Submit A Suggestion!'),
]
    .map(command => command.toJSON());

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), { body: commands })
    .then(() => console.log('Successfully registered application commands.'))
    .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: The title should be a short description of what your problem is and not what you do. Further more you should avoid writing a wall of text and split the text into some logical blocks to make it easier to read. And you should double-check if everything is formatted properly.

Comment: So the error happens at this line `let messageArgs = args.join(' ');`?

Comment: You had the same error yesterday. You're only passing the `interaction` at `command.execute(interaction)` yet you're expecting `message`, `args`, etc at `execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord)`. As `args` is undefined you receive _"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'join')"_

Comment: so how would I approach it to fix?

Answer (score 1):

You're only passing the interaction at `command.execute(interaction)` yet you're expecting `message`, `args`, etc at `execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord)`. As `args` is undefined you receive *"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'join')"* .

Another problem is that you're using v13 of discord.js and still having some v12 syntax, just like in [your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70728468/6126373).

As you are using slash commands, you will have no `args`, you could add a string option in your `deploy-commands.js` file using the [`addStringOption()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/builders/stable/class/SlashCommandBuilder?scrollTo=addStringOption) method. You should also mark this command option as required by using the [`setRequired()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/builders/stable/class/SlashCommandStringOption?scrollTo=setRequired) method.

Update `commands` in `deploy-commands.js`:

```js
const commands = [
  new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('suggest')
    .setDescription('Submit a suggestion!')
    .addStringOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName('suggestion')
        .setDescription('Enter your suggestion')
        .setRequired(true),
    ),
].map((command) => command.toJSON());
```

In your `suggestions.js` file, you can get this option from the `CommandInteractionOptionResolver` using [`interaction.options.getString('suggestion')`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteractionOptionResolver?scrollTo=getString).

There are some changes to how `setAuthor()` works in v13. It now accepts an [`EmbedAuthorData`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/EmbedAuthorData) object that has a `name` and an `iconURL` property.

Replace your `suggestions.js` with the following:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  name: 'suggest',
  aliases: ['suggest', 'suggestion'],
  permissions: [],
  description: 'creates a suggestion!',
  async execute(interaction) {
    let channel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.find((c) => c.name === 'suggestions');
    if (!channel) {
      await interaction.reply('`suggestions` channel does not exist!');
      return;
    }

    let suggestion = interaction.options.getString('suggestion');
    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('5104DB')
      .setAuthor({
        name: interaction.member.user.tag,
        iconURL: interaction.member.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }),
      })
      .setDescription(suggestion);

    let sentEmbed = await channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });

    await interaction.reply({
      content: ' Thanks, we have received your suggestion',
      ephemeral: true,
    });
    sentEmbed.react('❌');
    sentEmbed.react('✅');
  },
};
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: after changing the code in both .js files, the command executes only to the point after submitting the suggestion. I ran "node deploy-commands.js" followed by "node ." and the bot turns on, I went into the submit a suggestion chat and enter /suggest "Here is a suggestion test" and pressed enter, after the bot processes it then says "The application did not respond"

Comment: not in the terminal but in discord yes

Comment: maybe there's a package I don't have installed? Unsure why I'm getting this problem honestly.

Comment: Could you upload your `index.js`, `deploy-commands.js`, and `package.json` file somewhere and send a link here so I could look into it?

Comment: yes give me a second

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11G2URMcSpSC0ho_48YgDiNcIiO2w2bF-?usp=sharing

Comment: @senpai Thanks, there was a name mismatch and a missing dependency, I've just updated the code above. Can you please check if it works when you update your `suggestion.js` file?

Comment: yes it works perfect now with no hiccups, thank you so much!